# C++ builder How to access a specific cell in a DrawGrid

Tags: drawing, c++builder

I am working on a Tetris Game in C++ Builder. I want to draw my pieces on a TDrawGrid and I can't find anything that allows me to access a specific cell in which should I draw. I mean, I want to draw (for example) in column x=2 and row y=2;
I only found DrawGrid->CellRect(int, int). But that's not good, because I want to send (separated) the column and row as parameters in different functions, like MoveThePiece() and DrawThePiece();

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TDrawGrid` is an owner-drawn component. It does not keep track of any per-cell data, which is why you can't find anything related to that (unlike `TStringGrid`, which keeps track of strings and object pointers for you on a per-cell basis within its `Cells` property).

You will have to keep track of your own per-cell state data in your own code as needed.  Using the `OnDrawCell` event, draw each cell according to its current state.  Do not try to draw anything onto the grid from outside of that event.

For instance, you could allocate a 2-dimensional array to hold your cell data, where each element tracks whether a cell is empty or holds a (piece of a) tile.  Then, inside the `OnDrawCell` event, use the provided `Row` and `Col` parameters to index into the array to get the cell's current state, and then draw the cell as needed.

Alternatively, if you keep a list of active tiles instead, you can store row/column info for each tile.  Then inside the `OnDrawCell` event, you can find the tile that covers the specified `Row`/`Col` and if found then draw that (portion of the) tile within the cell, otherwise draw (that portion of) the background instead.

Either way, whenever you "move" a tile around, update the appropriate array/list elements as needed, and then `Invalidate()` the entire grid (or at least `InvalidateCell()` the affected cells) to trigger a repaint.

That being said, you might consider using `TPaintBox` instead of `TDrawGrid`.  Using its `OnPaint` event, you can draw whatever you want, wherever you want.  Keeping a list of active tiles and their current x/y coordinates, and then simply drawing all of the active tiles when `OnPaint` is triggered, makes things a bit easier to manage without having to worry about the granularity of dealing with individual cells.